# Three triangles passing through every dot of a 5x5 grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry

25 dots are drawn as a 5x5 regular square grid. Can you draw 3 triangles that pass through every dot? The corners of the triangles must lie on the dots, ie., they cannot lie outside the grid.

Comment: i wonder what is the fewest number of triangles needed if right triangles are forbidden?

Comment: @jwezorek great idea! I've made this into a new puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110702/four-non-right-angled-triangles-passing-through-every-dot-of-a-5x5-grid

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is the only solution.
(Edit: It isn't. See teedyay's answer for another solution.)

> [image]

I found this solution mostly by trial and error, but I did keep in mind that

> apart from the 9 triangle vertices there are 25-9=16 other vertices that need to lie on the 9 sides of the triangles, so on average the sides need to visit almost 2 extra vertices each. That makes it almost inevitable that all triangles have two axis-aligned sides and a third 45-degree side, and that one triangle covers two whole sides of the grid.

Comment: Correct and well done! I will post a harder version of this puzzle soon.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an alternative solution to the one already found:

> [image: Alternative solution]

Comment: Oh very nice! I didn't realise that there was another solution.

Comment: After seeing the solution for the [7x7 version of the problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110690/20814) I should have realised that trick might apply here as well. Very well done for finding this!

Answer (score 16):

Another symmetric solution:

> [image]

> This was found by noticing that @teedyay's solution has quite a bit of slack in it.

In fact, there are two more similar solutions:

> [image]
>  [image]