# Four triangles passing through every dot of a 7x7 grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry

49 dots are drawn as a 7x7 regular square grid. Can you draw 4 triangles that pass through every dot? The corners of the triangles must lie on the dots, ie., they cannot lie outside the grid.

The 7x7 puzzle is a harder version of the 5x5 puzzle: [Three triangles passing through every dot of a 5x5 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110688/three-triangles-passing-through-every-dot-of-a-5x5-grid)

Comment: @msh210 Changed the wording to make it clear.

Comment: It is even less clear than before (a slight difference between "this is a link:" and "here is a link: ...". But information from the other puzzle clarifies that 4,7x7 is harder than 3,5x5.

Comment: I can get all but one...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The construction:

> [image]

I don't know if it's the only solution, but that's the only one I found.

Comment: That last triangle (green in your picture) is so hard to find / easy to overlook! This is a great puzzle and well done on finding the solution. I'm almost sure it is the only solution (up to rotation/reflection).

Comment: Correct and well done! Yes that green triangle is very hard to find. If we use the approach in the previous 5x5 puzzle then it is not too hard to find a solution with one dot missing. But getting that extra dot is the challenge here.

Comment: @Ausername That's quite unlucky... I feel bad for you :(

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks! Nice puzzle!

Comment: @JerryDean I think it's time you change the quote in your profile ;)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I planned to change it every 3 months or so to keep track of how I'm doing here ;) (That's why I wrote the date as well)

Comment: I did the computer search.  It is the only solution modulo symmetries and permutations of the triangles.  And btw if you go for non-right triangles you need 6 of them.